# How to link a Qt application against xmlpatterns with qmake under Windows

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have the following .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += qml quick xmlpatterns
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

Moreover, I have the following main.cpp in my Qt project (in Qt Creator, using Qt 5.5):

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtXmlPatterns>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QXmlSchema schema;

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

This code doesn't compile, even though the xmlpatterns example in my Qt installation does compile. What am I missing here???

Qt Creator doesn't find the header QtXmlPatterns (which exists, I checked that) and if I replace

```
#include <QtXmlPatterns>
```

with

```
#include <QtXmlPatterns/QtXmlPatterns>
```

Qt Creator finds the header but can't link against the QtXmlPatterns lib:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QXmlSchema::QXmlSchema(void)" (__imp_??0QXmlSchema@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QXmlSchema::~QXmlSchema(void)" (__imp_??1QXmlSchema@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
debug\BrainReliefer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

How can I get this application compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally upgraded to Qt 5.6 and it works.